# How to move a module from root to a subpackage maintinaing backwards compatability

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-import, python-packaging

This is the original structure of a project:

```
project/
  mypackage
    __init__.py
    moduleA.py
```

I want to move `moduleA.py` to a sub package:

```
project/
  mypackage
    __init__.py
    subpackage
      __init__.py
      moduleA.py
```

I need to **maintain backward compatability** so that old code using `import mypackage.moduleA` still works.

I tried adding this to `project/mypackage/__init__.py`:

```
from subpackage import moduleA
```

That allows me to `import mypackage.moduleA`. But unfortunately it forces `moduleA` to be imported as soon as `mypackage` is imported, which is not what I want (I am making `moduleA` an optional package, so dependencies are not guaranteed).

Can I still enable `mypackage.moduleA` imports using lazy module loading when `import mypackage` runs? The user should explicitly import `mypackage.moduleA` to trigger the import.

Comment: You could write a stub `mypackage.moduleA` that `from .submodule.modulaA import the good stuff`. This has limitations. It should work fine for functions and classes but global variables in the real moduleA would be a problem.

Comment: This is possible. I was hoping to avoid the lingering file, but it would be easy to add a deprecation notice there. I was hoping something a little cleaner might exist.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use a [module level getattr](https://peps.python.org/pep-0562/) hook to lazy load "moduleA" on first use.

```
# in mypackage/__init__.py

some_other_name = 123

def __getattr__(name):
    global moduleA
    if name == "moduleA":
        from mypackage.subpackage import moduleA
        return moduleA
    raise AttributeError(name)
```

*Requires Python-3.7+*. Note that the getattr is only invoked for names that aren't otherwise found in the namespace, so `from mypackage import some_other_name` will not invoke the hook and won't trigger an early import of the subpackage.

This will work:

```
from mypackage import moduleA
```

This will also work:

```
import mypackage
mypackage.moduleA
```

Though **be aware of one important caveat to maintain backward compatibility.** A direct submodule import will *not* work, because the submodule is not actually there to be found by the import system directly:

```
import mypackage.moduleA
```

To avoid breaking this form of import statement, you may still include a `mypackage/moduleA.py` file (which can be a deprecation shim)

```
# in mypackage/moduleA.py
import warnings
warnings.warn(
    message="mypackage.moduleA has moved to mypackage.subpackage.moduleA",
    category=DeprecationWarning,
    stacklevel=2,
)

from mypackage.subpackage.moduleA import *
```

The deprecation notice should hang around for a couple of releases, and then you can remove `mypackage/moduleA.py` entirely in the next breaking release, being sure to [mention the change in your release notes](https://keepachangelog.com/).